# Ajax request for Mysql data update fails at 1000 row updates using IN command

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP based code that uses ajax to update MYSQL records.  It works fine for 500, 900, but at 1000, it fails and I get an error not related to MYSQL, it seems.  Development is on a localhost, Xampp/Windows 10 platform, PHP 7+. The error code I get through the Chrome troubleshooting console is:

```
Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\Data\anyCompany\notify\notify_ajax.php on line 54
```

The routine gathers all the checkboxes in a list on the page and sets them all to a 1 or 0.  The user can choose the amount he wants.  I was going to limit it to 1000, but it seems this number is failing for some reason...?

The Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/notify/notify_ajax.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{action:'set_all_read_checkboxes',
          read_checkbox_id_array:read_checkbox_id_array, //array of database table id's to change
          read_all_set_checkbox_value:read_all_set_checkbox_value}, // value to change them to
    success:function(data){
          console.log(data);                  
    }
});
```

The ajax processing file/code.  The index it is complaining about is passed via ajax as the first parameter.  Works fine for all quantities except when I hit 1000.

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'set_all_read_checkboxes' ){
    $read_checkbox_id_array = implode(",",$_POST['read_checkbox_id_array']); //array of database table id's to change
    $read_all_set_checkbox_value = $_POST['read_all_set_checkbox_value']; // value to change them to
    
    $sql = 'UPDATE emails SET web_viewed = ? WHERE email_id IN ('.$read_checkbox_id_array.')';
    $db->prepare($sql)->execute([$read_all_set_checkbox_value]);
    echo $read_checkbox_id_array.'/'.$read_all_set_checkbox_value;//for console feedback verification only
}
```

Is it a timeout issue due to a larger amount of transfer data or ?  What can I change in my code to accommodate this or test the issue further to get some more clues as to the actual problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"fails at 1000"_ - 1000 what? Is it 1000 checkboxes/id's you're sending to PHP? Is the value 1000? Please clarify the question. Remember that we only know what you tell and show us.

Comment: This is updating Mysql records.  One checkbox id correspond to one row in the dbase table.  Sending 1000 id numbers, like "342,543,454,654..." corresponds to 1000 row id's in the database that get updated.  Hope that  make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `max_input_vars` setting in your `php.ini` to prevent deny of service attack. By default it's set to 1000.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

Comment: Seems to have worked.  The php.ini file had this commented out, but was at 1000, so it must have defaulted to 1000.  Increased to 10,000 and removed comment out and it worked!  Thank you!

Comment: Question to Fiouze - the php.ini file says, "; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted.  max_input_vars = 10000" .  My array of 1000 id's is all in ONE array variable as you can see in the code.  So, doesn't this count as just ONE input variable that gets passed in a POST input variable, and NOT 1000 variables?

Comment: That's a good question. I would think it counts as 1 variable but from what you say in your previous answer it seems that each entry in the array counts as 1. Maybe someone can tell you more about this